# get the last modified date from ALAsset (Video) iOS Video

Tags: ios, video, metadata, last-modified

How would I get the last modified date from ALAsset type video?

I tried with:

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[[[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata] objectForKey:@"{TIFF}"] objectForKey:@"DateTime"]];
```

but metadata is coming empty for a video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ALAsset Class reference there is no such property for Last updated date how ever there is a property for Created date

```
ALAsset* asset;
NSDate* date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
```

Comment: So, it is no way to get the last modified date of a Video?